Italian and British Passport
I have an italian passport as both parents italian but born in england so I also have a british passport.
I love using my Italian passport yet when I return the UK using italian passport (where I live, work and have a home) I have been questioned and stopped by border control and I am confused as to why and which passport to use??

You may remember that a few years ago that thing called Brexit happened.
Since this took effect, EU citizens no longer have freedom of movement in the UK. Without additional paperwork (resident permit, EUSS…), they are no longer allowed to live or work in the UK.
Since you are also a British citizen, these restrictions do not apply to you, but the only way for them to know that is to show your UK passport.
So the usual rules apply: use your Italian passport when you travel to Italy (or anywhere in the EU, really), and your UK passport when you travel to the UK:

going to Italy:

Airline: Italian passport
No exit passport control in the UK
Italian passport control: Italian passport


Going to the UK:

Airline: UK passport
Italian passport control: Italian passport
UK passport control: UK passport




thanks - usually when booking the flights I book departure and return and have to enter the passenger information via the airline. How would I do that when I can only input one set of details - is this what you mean in your step by step "airline: italian passport"

@LidiaKelly if the names are the same then it is simple: enter the details of the first passport you will use whenever you're asked for passport details before the first flight.  Enter the details of the other passport when you check in for the return flight.  If the names are different then it is slightly more complicated; you'll always enter the Italian passport but will show the UK passport to UK border officers -- and to the airline if they ever ask about your right to remain in the UK.

@LidiaKelly it depends on the airline. Some allow two passports or one passport per flight. Many allow you to edit your passport info whenever you want, so after the first flight you can change to the other passport for the return flight. Otherwise most airlines allow you to do it at check-in time (the last info always overwrites any previous data). A few will charge you for that, in which case you leave it as is and only show the relevant passport at the destination border control (but with the generalisation of ESTA, ETA, ETIAS etc, it becomes more and more awkward).


and I am confused as to why and which passport to use??

The reason why, is because you are only showing your non-UK passport which does not prove that you have the right of abode in the UK.
Since you already have a UK passport, you are not eligible for a certificate of entitlement (see link below) which would be a sticker in your non-UK passport.
Therefore you should use your UK passport to enter the UK and your Italian passport when entering the Schengen area to avoid all immigration restrictions.


Prove you have right of abode in the UK

certificate of entitlement

Fee: £550 in (or outside) the UK
You cannot get a certificate if you already have a British passport or a valid certificate of entitlement in another foreign passport





